# writing to file in multithreaded app fails vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, multithreading, io, streamwriter

I have a multi threaded app that writes log to file. occasionaly, saving fails using this code

```
Friend Sub SaveToText(ByVal FileName As String, ByVal Text As String)
        '// create a writer and open the file
        Dim objLock As New Object
        SyncLock objLock

            Dim tw As TextWriter = Nothing
            Try
                '// write a line of text to the file
                tw = New StreamWriter(FileName, True)
                tw.Write(Text)
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error saving", _
                                MessageBoxButtons.OK, _
                                MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            Finally
                '// close the stream
                If tw IsNot Nothing Then
                    tw.Close()
                    tw.Dispose()
                End If

            End Try
        End SyncLock
    End Sub
```

The error message i get

> The process cannot access the file 'error.log' because it is being
>   used by another process.

Which other way can i make this safe?

Comment: What other process would have that file locked?  Your virus scanner? Another copy of your program?  A different program?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
    Dim objLock As New Object
```

Your SyncLock statement doesn't lock anything.  Every thread will gets its own instance of objLock since it is a local variable and gets allocated every time the method is entered.  Move the declaration outside of the method so it becomes a member of your class.  And make sure there is only one instance of that class.  Or make it Shared ReadOnly.

Comment: thanks for responding, this code is in a module, does you solution still applies?

Comment: You automatically get Shared.  You do need to create objLock yourself, using As New isn't good enough.  Do so in code that runs before any of the threads get started.